# Grid inside flex with fixed-width left and right sidebars

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to make following with html and css:
[Image sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcAqD.png)

Basically, I want to accomplish this:

- Left and Right sidebars have 200px width always and they dont have paddings or margins themselves (they have 100% height)
- In the middle there is grid div with 12 columns and grid-gap of 10px

How grid is structured itself is not important (i know this part), but i fail to align divs (left, grid and right sidebar) in correct order.

```css
#container{
 display: flex;
}

#left-sidebar{
 background-color: blue;
 height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
}

#grid{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
 grid-gap: 10px;
 height: 100vh;
 padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

#right-sidebar{
 background-color: blue;
 height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
}

#g1{
 background-color: orange;
 grid-column: 1 / 4;
 grid-row: 1 / last-line;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

#g2{
 background-color: red;
 grid-column: 4 / 13;
 grid-row: 1 / last-line;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="left-sidebar"></div>
  
  <div id="grid">
    <div id="g1"></div>
    <div id="g2"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="right-sidebar"></div>
  
 </div>
```

**I want grid to be inbetween those two sidebars...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a 200px padding on the left and right to your grid, so it is between the sidebars.

```css
#container{
 display: flex;
}

#left-sidebar{
 background-color: blue;
 height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
}

#grid{
  padding-left: 200px !important;
padding-right: 200px !important;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
 grid-gap: 10px;
 height: 100vh;
 padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

#right-sidebar{
 background-color: blue;
 height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
}

#g1{
 background-color: orange;
 grid-column: 1 / 4;
 grid-row: 1 / last-line;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

#g2{
 background-color: red;
 grid-column: 4 / 13;
 grid-row: 1 / last-line;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="left-sidebar"></div>
  
  <div id="grid">
    <div id="g1"></div>
    <div id="g2"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="right-sidebar"></div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Ok, would you consider that good solution? There is no way that each of those 3 divs "know" for each other and they align automatically?

Comment: this is totally ok! because you have position: fixed, your sidebars are removed from "normal" flow, thats why you have behaviour like in your question. either go with the padding as i suggested or try not to use position: fixed and leave your sidebar divs in normal flow

Comment: Ok, i made it like that now. Thank you :)